# Properly exposing a Rails server on :80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache

I have a Rails server (Apache/CentOS-backed) that's accessible at mydomain.com:3000, but I'd like it to be exposed at :80 so I can access it at just mydomain.com.  As best I can tell, this should be done through Apache's `httpd.conf` file.  Mine contains the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin my-email@gmail.com
  #RailsEnv development
  DocumentRoot /var/www/webapps/railsSite/public
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ErrorLog logs/mydomain.com-error_log
  CustomLog logs/mydomain.com-access_log common

 <directory /var/www/webapps/railsSite/public>
   AllowOverride all
   Options -MultiViews
 </directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Am I missing anything from this block?

I'm starting my server via the standard `rails server` command.  I looked up starting it directly to :80 via `rvmsudo rails server -p 80`, but I get an error saying `sudo: rails: command not found`.  Somehow, sudo's not able to find `rails`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are instructions here for the passenger gem https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

Comment: That's a massive page I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for within it.  By searching just "port" and reading the surrounding bits, it doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: What are you using to run your rails app, passenger, unicorn, puma? You need something to run your app. Passenger is the most widely used probably, at least the easiest to setup.

Comment: I have Passenger.  So far as I can tell, this don't contain anything on either redirecting from :80 to a Rails server running on another port or fixing the `rvmsudo` issue that's preventing me from running it directly on :80.

Comment: No, because you're not supposed to use it that way.